# how to insert symbols in a text string using regex in Atom (Mac OS)

Tags: regex, atom-editor, regex-lookarounds

I need to insert a prefix in a hexadecimal string before every 2 characters.
My first thought was using lookaround like

```
(?=[0-9a-f]{2})
```

but obviously it won't work because it finds every position that has two symbols after, not every other position.
The line is:

```
d0bfd0bed181d182d183d0bfd0b8d0bbd0be
```

I can use (?=d[01]) and (?<=d[01]) because the line contains only lowercase cyrillic letters but if possible I need a more universal solution.

Another problem is that Atom editor, as it seems, can't insert anything in a negative space found by a working lookaround expression. Replacement works with position regexes like ^ or $ but not with lookarond/lookbehind expressions.

If it cannot be done in Atom please recommend a good code&text editor for Mac OS that understands perl flavour regex for editing.

Comment: Did you try something like `([0-9a-f]{2})` and replacing with `0$1` (to add `0` before the two hex chars)? (Looks like [there is no support for `$0`](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/1127)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
([0-9a-f]{2})
```

and replace with `<your_prefix>$1` to add a prefix to the matched string.

Unfortunately, [there is no support for `$0` backreference](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/1127) in Atom, so you will have to use an outer capturing group round the whole pattern.